# Sending public channel reply Telegram messages with Telethon

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm working with Telethon have been able to successfully send messages as well as pull public channel messages sent by other members, but I was wondering if there is a way to reply via sendmessage to an already posted message. The sent reply would be attached to the original posting.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient


def messages(api_id, api_hash, phone, channel_name, message_content, 
destination_channel_id):
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
    client.connect()
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        client.send_code_request(phone)
        client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
    destination_channel_username = channel_name
    entity = client.get_entity(destination_channel_username)
    client.send_message(entity, message_content)
    client.disconnect()

def channel_chat(api_id, api_hash, phone, chat):
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
    client.connect()
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        client.send_code_request(phone)
        client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
    for message in client.iter_messages(chat, from_user='me', reverse=True):
        return message
        quit()
    client.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    api_id = "api_id"
    api_hash = "api_hash"
    phone = "phone)
    chat = "channel_name"

    last_message = channel_chat(api_id, api_hash, phone, chat)
    if last_message:
        print("ID{} - {}".format(last_message.id, last_message.message))
        messages(api_id, api_hash, phone, chat, 'Thank you', last_message.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reply_to` parameter of [`send_message`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.send_message) to reply to a specific message:

```py
client.send_message(entity, message_content, reply_to=msg_id_of_destination_channel)
```

This will work as long as the message you're trying to reply to exists in the chat where your new message is being sent. You may need to define a `dict` which maps the identifiers of all messages between the two channels if all you have is the message ID of the source channel.

As a side note, this is a very expensive operation:

```py
entity = client.get_entity(destination_channel_username)
```

You should consider using `get_input_entity`, and cache the result.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please make sure to mark the answer as accepted.